# Structure data to compare values using Firebase with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know if my way of structuring data is the best method or not. The reason I have wondered about this is due to the complex requirements that I need from the data.

I am trying to check if the *users* list of ingredients matches the *recipes* list of ingredients and be able to display and count them. For example:

**Ingredient count**

`1/2 ingredients`

**User has**

`Dough`

**User doesn't have**

`Mozzarella`

The data structure for my recipe currently looks like this:

```
{
  "RecipeData": {
    "-KlKMkBekJ6plrXI5cZV": {
      "name": "Pizza",
      "ingredients": {
        "-KkY8kL_wvxrcqMn_aP_": true,
        "-KkbS1pYW_9l4y4HPuog": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The details of the ingredients i.e. *name* is taken from a dictionary:

```
{
  "IngredientData": {
    "ingredients": {
      "-KkbS1pYW_9l4y4HPuog": {
        "name": "Dough"
      },
      "-KkY8kL_wvxrcqMn_aP_": {
        "name": "Mozzarella"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how it looks when a user adds their own ingredients:

```
{
  "users": {
    "Ss5XNpWJ5IfIuYiMqsxTnMgjNrm1": {
      "usersList": {
        "-KlKuq2xjbQcR3ZMsHF1": {
          "name": "Dough"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this data structure I have found it difficult to compare the values of the *users* list of ingredients with the *recipe's* list of ingredients.

### **Update:**

I have a `Ingredient` class that handles the properties inside users ingredients, I also use this to when getting the names of the ingredients inside the recipe:

```
class Ingredient {

    var name: String?
    var key: String?

    init(from snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]

        self.key = snapshot.key
        self.ref = snapshot.ref
        self.name = snapshotValue?["name"] as? String
    }
```

I also have an `IngredientManager` which has the array of ingredients inside where I am able to call it anywhere.

I have a `Recipe` class that handles the properties inside a recipe:

```
class Recipe {

    var name: String!
    var ingredients = [String]()
    var key: String


    init(from snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

        self.name = snapshotValue["name"] as? String
        self.key = snapshot.key

        recipeIng(snapshot: snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "ingredients"))


    }
    // Function to count the number of ingredients inside recipe... this works
    func recipeIng(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {

        for item in snapshot.children {

            guard let ing = item as? FIRDataSnapshot else { continue }
            // Gets the key and turns it into a string and then appends it to the array.
            guard let value = ing.key as? String else { return }

            ingredients.append(value)
        }
    }


    // Function to match the ingredients.
    func matchedIngredients() -> ([String], [String]) {

        var userHas = [String]()
        var userHasNot = [String]()

        // loops through the users ingredients
        for ingedient in IngredientManager.shared.ingredients {
            // loops through the recipe's ingredients
            for i in ingredients {

                if ingedient.name == r {
                    userHas.append(i)
                } else {
                   userHasNot.append(i)
                }
            }
        }
        return (userHas, userHasNot)
    }
}
```

I am able to count the number of ingredients inside a recipe but right now I am struggling to compare that with the *users* list of ingredients. `ingredient.name` is able to get the name of the *users* ingredients which is what I'd like to use to compare it with as the key for the *users* ingredients are completely different to the *recipes*.

This is how I display it on a label:

```
ingredientLbl.text = "\(recipe.matchedIngredients().0.count)/\(recipe.ingredients.count)"
```

Comment: It looks fine to me. It'll probably be easier to help if you show what you've tried. I'd expect a loop over one list, where you remove item from both lists if it exists in both. At the end of the loop, the lists should both be empty.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen please see my updated answer, if you'd like me to show you how I can get the names of each ingredient inside recipe I can, I just didn't want to to look like I am just posting lots of codes.

Comment: I think the crux of your problem is in your last sentence: "the key for the users ingredients are completely different to the recipes". To allow comparing ingredients, you really ought to use the same key for them. It *can* also work based on comparing names, but the code will be harder to read/maintain.

Comment: I had a feeling that was the issue. I was wondering if you could help direct me to let the user add ingredients which has the same keys as the ingredients for the recipe. At the moment I have had to manually add the ingredients into the recipe i.e. ` "-KkbS1pYW_9l4y4HPuog": true`. I am not sure how to add an ingredient taken from the ingredient dictionary to the users list. If this question is irrelevant to the initial question for this post then I shall ask it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the extra lookup, it becomes a bit of a nesting exercise. But if you read through the loops it's actually not all that difficult. In JavaScript this does the trick:

```js
ref.child("users").once("value").then((usersSnapshot) => {
  usersSnapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
    ref.child("RecipeData").once("value").then((recipesSnapshot) => {
      recipesSnapshot.forEach((recipeSnapshot) => {
        var userNeeds = [];
        recipeSnapshot.child("ingredients").forEach((recipeIngredientSnapshot) => {
          userNeeds.push(ingredientsData[recipeIngredientSnapshot.key].name); // assume the user needs this
          var recipeIngredientName = ingredientsData[recipeIngredientSnapshot.key];
          userSnapshot.child("usersList").forEach((userIngredientSnapshot) => {
            var index = userNeeds.indexOf(userIngredientSnapshot.val().name)
            if (index >= 0) {
              userNeeds.splice(index, 1);
            }
          });
          console.log("User "+userSnapshot.key+" "+(userNeeds.length?"cannot":"can")+" make "+recipeSnapshot.key+": missing ingredients "+userNeeds);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

A working jsbin: https://jsbin.com/ziqobow/edit?js,console

The key that I do differently here is that I first assume that the user doesn't have each necessary ingredient, and then remove that assumption if it turns out they *do* already have the ingredient.

Comment: Sorry, but would you be able to write this in Swift as the question asks please.